# Is Next.js API folder and files safe to store something like API Key, secret word, etc?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to build a simple Next.js route that handles payments. In that route's handler I'm commentating with a third-party service via fetch to process a payment. One of the headers is a token (**a secure token that should not be visible to anyone**). I'm keeping the token in a string variable inside the route handler and using it in the fetch call.

My question is, *is this safe*? Is the API folder exposed to the front-end like everything else?

Answer (score 7):

Everything added into the api folder will never reach the client side, however is recommended and considered as a good practice to save your sensitive data in .env file

Answer (score 4):

API folder is not exposed on frontend you can safely store the token it will not be visible on frontend

once you add code on you /api folder it will be on server side unless you expose your token through res.send/res.json() or show the source code to other people then they will see your token. if you want you could add your token in [environment variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables)